# Fixed-Dimension Specialization for Linear-Algebra Packages in D

Tags: d, linear-algebra

D can specialize functions on constant arguments (known in compile-time), typically for `pow(base, exponent)` if `exponent` is a constant integer. As C++ lacks this feature it instead have to resort to template-specialization-hacks that obscure the API for example the `pow` function-template in Boost.Units.

But, couldn't constant arguments specialization also be used in linear algebra packages to specialize matrix operations such matrix-vector-multiply for fixed dimension cases such as 2x2, 3x3, 3x3, 4x3 and 4x4 generally used in 2-D/3-D graphics. These overloads are typically implemented using SIMD instructions (intrinsics) and it would be fantastic if these implementations could be picked automatically by such a library for matrices and vectors of suitable fixed size.

I believe this would be a real killer application for D, especially in scientific visualization. This is because the bridge between higher/dynamic-dimension linear algebra and fixed-dimension 2-D/3-D could be made completely transparent to a developer making use of a package implementing these ideas.

There are already several nice 2-, 3-, and 4-D linear-algebra packages for D such as gl3n.
I would love to see it be extended to provide functions contained in C++ libraries such as Eigen and Armadillo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, couldn't constant arguments specialization also be used in linear algebra packages to specialize matrix operations such matrix-vector-multiply for fixed dimension cases such as 2x2, 3x3, 3x3, 4x3 and 4x4 generally used in 2d/3d graphics.

Yes, this is entirely possible, and quite easy. There's a few ways you can do it:

- Use template specialisation.
- Use template function constraints.
- Use `static if`.

Here's an example using `static if` for vector addition.

```
Vec!N add(int N)(Vec!N a, Vec!N b)
{
    static if (N == 4)
    {
        // Use vector ops
    }
    else
    {
        // Use generic routine
    }
}
```

The `static if` is evaluated at compile time, so there is no branching cost at run time.

Comment: This is however possible in C++ aswell through template specialization on, in this case, `add`. My main question was if constant argument specialization could enable even more flexible behaviour not possible in C++ for functions other than the `pow` example mentioned above.

Comment: No, you cannot detect constant arguments automatically. Doing so would break the compilation model of D (how can a function specialise itself, without the source, after it has been compiled?) In theory it could be done using templates, but it hasn't.